# Soundcloud API in Angular SC.get not pausing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

My soundcloud Angular app will play music, but it won't pause. Here's the code.

```
  $scope.stream = function() {
    console.log('something');
    SC.stream('/tracks/329').then(function(player) {
      if ($scope.playing === true) {
        player.pause();
        $scope.playing = false;
        console.log("pause");
      } else {
        player.play();
        $scope.playing = true;
        console.log("play");
      }
      console.log($scope.playing + ' currently');
    });
```

Other solutions aren't very dry and split this into two functions utilizing ng-show and ng-hide. I suppose I may do that, but I'm perplexed as to why this doesn't work though $scope.playing does toggle between true and false.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, each time you call SC.stream, you create a new player object. It was being called every time I called the function. Here's the code that works if anyone wants to do the if statement:

```
$scope.stream = function() {
  if (!$scope.track) {
    SC.stream('/tracks/329').then(function(player) {
      $scope.track = player;
      player.play();
    });
  } else {
    $scope.track.pause();
    $scope.track = !$scope.track;
  }
};
```

However, I've since found a better solution. It doesn't appear as dry, but it works quite efficiently:

```
  $scope.play = function(id) {
    soundcloud.stream(id).then(function(player) {
      $scope.player = player;
      $scope.player.play();
    });
    $scope.isPlaying = id;
  };

  $scope.pause = function(id) {
    $scope.player.pause();
    $scope.isPlaying = false;
  };
```

- `$scope.isPlaying` replaced `$scope.playing` and gets moved outside of the callback. This way it grabs the id everytime the play() function is called.
- You'll also notice that `SC.stream()` has been replaced with `soundcloud.stream()`. I decided to throw `SC.stream()` into a service. This may or may not be better, but it feels like it's what you *should* do for angular applications since `SC.*` is a call to the API.
- The pause() function gets separated. It looks like this is common for ng applications vs if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Above code dangling the player with playing true false.

Try this

```
$scope.playing = true; // for initial play 

$scope.stream = function() {
console.log('something');
SC.stream('/tracks/329').then(function(player) {
  if ($scope.playing === true) {
    player.pause();
    console.log("pause");
  } else {
    player.play();
    console.log("play");
  }
  console.log($scope.playing + ' currently');
});
//make some click event that handle player state
$scope.onClick = function(){
   $scope.playing = !$scope.playing;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having trouble. Do I call both functions in the HTML? E.g., `ng-click="onClick(); stream()"` Or how to I initiate both functions? I actually tried adding this to my html, but it didn't work.